# Confusion on Silverlight user control custom property binding

Tags: silverlight, binding, customproperty

I have UserControl, named `thisUserControl`, it has two controls as shown in the following XAML code:

```
<UserControl
    ...
    x:Name="thisUserControl">
    <StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Button x:Name="btnChangeString" Content="Change String" Click="btnChangeString_Click" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=StringProperty, ElementName=thisUserControl}" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

BTW, I don't know why I have to set a name for `UserControl` so that I could use it for Binding in `ElementName=thisUserControl`. (I thought it should be `this` by default if `ElementName` is not provided)

I also defined the customer property for this UserControl, with some other code:

```
private string sp = "A String Here";
[Bindable(true)]
public string StringProperty
{
    get { return sp; }
    set { sp = value; }
}

private void btnChangeString_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    StringProperty = "Something Else";
}
```

When I compile and run it, click the "Change String" button, nothing happens.

It seems the `Bindable(true)` not working at all.  What does this `Bindable(true)` mean?

Is there an easy way to make a Custom Property bindable?  Let this UserControl inherit `INotifyPropertyChanged`? or use `DependencyProperty`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Bindable(true)` is a way for you to tell a GUI designer that a property supports two-way binding. However, to actually *implement* two-way binding, you have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for that property.

Also, if `ElementName` is not provided in a binding, the default is to bind to `DataContext`.

Comment: I added this `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"` for the default binding, and it works.  That Bindable(true) is really confusing.  I also tried INotifyPropertyChanged and it also works.  But INotifyPropertyChanged  does not work on MultiBinding: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/SilverlightMultiBinding.aspx